# Anaconda-Navigator - Logs of currently installing packages

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I have started the installation of these packages using Anaconda Navigator's GUI:

- pandas
- scikit-learn
- scipy
- tensorflow
- py-opencv
- futures
- py-pickle

For already 3 hours, it shows me a window with the text "The following packages will be modified" and below it, there is a relatively big empty text area, and after that, there is a loading bar with the left attached text "Solving package specifications...".

Is there any possibility to view the progress of the downloads of the packages? Any commands?

Thank you in advance.

[Window with loading bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8yuhs.png)